# Why do my C# Form closed when displayed?

Tags: c#, forms, dispose, show

i have 2 forms, those are form1.cs and form2.cs

on the form1, it has button1, which will call form2 to show

here's the button1 code

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
form2 form = new form2();

form2.show();   // to call form2

this.dispose(); //to dispose form1

}
```

and then form2 showed, and it closed suddenly. anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Added some code to my answer to show what I was meaning.

Answer (score 3):

When you close your main form with `this.dispose()` you are terminating the program causing form2 to be disposed also because you are diposing the reference to form2. You would be better off passing a reference to your form1 to form2 and using `this.Hide()` instead.

You can try something like this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.setParent(this);
            form.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }
    }
```

And in form2 to go back to form1

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form parentForm;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void setParent(Form value)
        {
            parentForm = value;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentForm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: He's disposing of the main form (form1) not form2. The dispose method has no access to form2 due to scope. form2 is not disposed explicitly by this code, but dies when the application dies (due to the disposal of the main form).

Comment: @Neowizard he is creating form2 in form1 therefore when form1 is diposed it will cause form2 to be disposed also. We are saying the same thing I changed the wording so that it is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
form2 form = new form2();

form2.show();   // to call form2

this.hide(); //to hide form1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if form1 is program starter then application will close . Hence instead

```
this.dispose();
```

U just write

```
this.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Show() does not wait for form2 to close before continuing to the next command (dispose).
This will end up in closing form2 because it's probably running on a background thread.

Use ShowDialog to hold the execution of Dispose until the second form closes.

Also, you can set the second form to run on a foreground thread. This way the second form will not be dependent on the life of the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this.Hide() which should hide your current form or use a thread to open the new form.

Example: [C# open a new form, and close a form...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/936c8ca3-0809-4ddb-890c-426521fe60f1)